# apt-get remove messages (triggers for shared-mime-info): Unknown media type in type '...'

Tags: apt, uninstall, mime-type

I uninstalled quite a few programs today and in every removal there are the following messages on terminal. What are they supposed to mean? Is something to be fixed?

[image]

I have seen that there are similar questions but they are outdated. My question's point is to see if there is currently a way to fix it, so if someone wants to vote to close this one I would advice them against it.

Comment: @ByteCommander The related answers and questions are really outdated. My question's point is to see if there is currently a way to fix it. So if someone wants to vote to close this one I would advice them against it.

Comment: The question I linked (which is not the only one, there are way too many) might be old, but it is unfortunately still valid and not outdated at all. It seems like folks are not going to fix this properly... :-/

Comment: @ByteCommander Great! :P

Comment: @Adam If you read the link in the accepted answer in the link that ByteCommander gave, you will notice the bug report is still open. Hence, the answer is still valid even if it is old.

Comment: @edwinksl Thanks. I understand that, that is why I said great before..It was ironical as they haven't fixed such an issue for so many years.

Comment: @Adam One little thing you can do is to go the bug report, click on "Does this bug affect you?" and then "Yes, it affects me".

Comment: @ubashu Other people have already mentioned that, and I have already mentioned in my question that I have seen all these posts beforehand.